# ASP.NET redirect error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have controller "HomeController" class with two actions ("Index" and "Login"). By condition I must redirect user from "Index" to "Login". I tried next code:

```
if(HomeController.LoggedIn()) {
    return View();
}
else {
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home", new { area = "" });
}
```

But it throws error :

```
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object):     System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String name, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary values, System.Boolean& usingAreas) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String name, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary values) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl (System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, If I simple go to /Home/Login - Login action works right

Comment: Sorry, it was error in used MVC realization (now I'm testing work of application with Mono (yes, strange idea))

Answer (score 0):

To specify the default area, just use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
```

Comment: Code-only answers, especially short ones, are often flagged as low quality. You should add some explanation as to why this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure about even route config as per requirement is there or not ?

```
Or
```

try to pass a value in thirs parameter as id or value like:

```
if(HomeController.LoggedIn()) {
    return View();
}
else {
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home", "");
}
```